# Overload assignment operator with string parameter

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a type defined in C++ the following way:

```
class MyTypeT
{
public:
    MyTypeT();
    virtual ~MyTypeT();

    /// Initialize from string
    bool fromString(const std::string &typeinfo);

    /// Write to string
    virtual std::string toString() const;

    /// Is instance empty (not initialized yet)
    bool empty() const;
};
```

I was thinking to overload the assignment operator like this:

```
MyTypeT & MyTypeT::operator=(const std::string & rhs)
{
    fromString(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Is this allowed and useful approach or are there any side effects?

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: Better create `MyTypeT(std::string)` constructor and no need in multiple overloading all operators for you type and `std::string` and any other, only for you type.

Comment: Allowed: yes. Useful: no.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Why not?

Comment: Depending on how your code then uses the class, it may or may not be a good idea.   As a rough rule of thumb, if you provide an `operator=()` you need to provide a corresponding constructor.